# java web application with glassfish server not getting deployed

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

When I run my web project with glassfish server 4.1 , it says module has not been deployed.

```
GlassFish Server 4.1 is running.
Starting GlassFish Server 4.1
In-place deployment at /Users/shobhnit/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication3/build/web
GlassFish Server 4.1, deploy, null, false
/Users/shobhnit/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication3/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 minute 6 seconds)
```

My glassfish server is not getting started also  :

[server log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/929G9.png)

[glassfish server properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M77TD.png)

Comment: you've chopped off the actual error from the server log. Can you upload it to pastebin or something similar?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tABVm7CJ .       here is the link to pastebin server log @Mike

Comment: The log in that link doesn't have any app deployment in it and no evidence of the error above. It looks like a fresh server starting up normally